# Integrate Protractor with selenium and testNG

Tags: angular, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have a well setup selenium framework which has around 700+ tests that we execute daily. Now some components/modules of the website that we tests are moving to Angular ie the UI for some pages is going to be implemented in Angular while other pages remain same.
My question is, is there a way I can have both Old tests as well as new tests with protactor in same project. In more simpler way, can I make a test suite that has tests written with Protactor and other test suite that has tests with regular web Driver?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a special reason that you want to use Protractor instead of WebDriver for Angular pages?

Comment: Not any special reasons. But I was going through the internet and I found in many places that it is easier to wait for particular events if we use protractor for angular pages. It was also mentioned that elements like ng-repeat, ... etc is difficult to locate through webDriver.

Comment: In that case i would **strongly recommend** you to implement new test cases using the platform you already use (i.e. WebDriver). Integrating two different platforms without good reason is not a good idea, I would say. From my experience: automating tests of Angluar web pages using WebDriver is generally no problem. I developed some handy methods to do alle the `waitFor` stuff and there is pelnty of documentation about that (ask google). On the other hand, I did an evaluation of Protractor and least for that very project, it was _not_ suitable. Just cos it's Angluar - you don't need Protractor.

Answer (score 2):

I did my research and found the best solution for me. I found a workaround of testing angular sites without using protractor but with the features that angular provides. In case someone else might need it I am providing the reference here:
[ngWebDriver](https://github.com/paul-hammant/ngWebDriver)

Hope this will help someone